# how to access value with Get trait

Tags: rust

I believe this is a basic rust question, however,
I am quite new to rust. The issue is in the following validate method implemented
for X in the below test , I am trying to modify and pass the hardcoded
value '10' to the method (not as function parameter ).
I was told that I can acheive this with the Get trait
found here https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/traits/trait.Get.html, however I do need an example on how to implement the Get trait to achieve this . From the test below, the call stack begins from decode, which then calls validate , I am trying to modify this code to access 10 using the Get trait how do I achieve this ? can a sample implementation be provided or some clear guidance

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
    struct ValidARange;
 
    type CheckARange = (ValidARange, QED);

    #[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, codec::Encode, codec::Decode)]
    struct X {
        a: u32,
        b: u32,
    }

    impl Validate<ValidARange> for X {
        fn validate(self) -> Result<X, &'static str> {
            if self.a > 10 {
                Err("Out of range")
            } else {
                Ok(self)
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_valid_a() {
        let valid = X { a: 10, b: 0xCAFEBABE };
        let bytes = valid.encode();
        assert_eq!(
            Ok(Validated { value: valid, _marker: PhantomData }),
            Validated::<X, CheckARange>::decode(&mut &bytes[..])
        );
    }
}


 below are deficitions for traits and structs used

#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, TypeInfo)]
pub struct Validated<T, U> {
    value: T,
    _marker: PhantomData<U>,
}
pub trait Validate<U>: Sized {
    fn validate(self) -> Result<Self, &'static str>;
}

impl<T: Validate<U> + Validate<V>, U, V> Validate<(U, V)> for T {

    fn validate(self) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        let value = Validate::<U>::validate(self)?;
        let value = Validate::<V>::validate(value)?;
        Ok(value)
    }
}

impl<T: codec::Decode + Validate<(U, V)>, U, V> codec::Decode for Validated<T, (U, V)> {
    fn decode<I: codec::Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        let value = Validate::validate(T::decode(input)?).map_err(Into::<codec::Error>::into)?;
        Ok(Validated { value, _marker: PhantomData })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you implement it with Get, you will have just 1 value for 1 type, e.g. ValidARange10 has 10, ValidARange42 has 42 and so on. So for each value you'll have to create a new type, which is not too far from hardcoding. Is it really what you want? Do you want this value be dynamic at runtime, or static at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Using Get the "10" value is still hardcoded in a bunch of places in types with this approach (as I mentioned in the comment).

I took a freedom to simplify a bit, but kept the essentials.

Using u32 instead of your X it looks like this:

```
pub trait Get<T> {
    fn get() -> T;
}

struct ValidInRange0to10;
struct ValidInRange0to42;

impl Get<u32> for ValidInRange0to10 {
    fn get() -> u32 { 10 }
}

impl Get<u32> for ValidInRange0to42 {
    fn get() -> u32 { 42 }
}

pub trait Validate<U>: Sized {
    fn validate(self) -> bool;
}

impl<U: Get<u32>> Validate<U> for u32 {
    fn validate(self) -> bool {
        self <= U::get()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Validate::<ValidInRange0to10>::validate(5));  // true
    println!("{}", Validate::<ValidInRange0to10>::validate(15)); // false
    println!("{}", Validate::<ValidInRange0to42>::validate(15)); // true
    println!("{}", Validate::<ValidInRange0to42>::validate(43)); // false
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4975a24845cd6b6cb9bc6e0c9adc09d4)